# Flask/Jquery - trying to request a value but this error appears: raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)

Tags: python, jquery, flask, request

I'm currently trying out some Jquery in combination with Flask. The problem which I'm facing is that if I want to do a request of a variable it gives me this Error "raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)".

Does anyone know how to fix this? I would like to enter a number in the input box and after pressing the "led on" button, I would like to print that value out on my terminal.

```
@app.route("/led/<int:state>", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def led(state):
    if state == 0:
        print("es ist 0")
    elif state == 1:
        intervall = request.form['intervallMinuten']
        print(intervall)
    else:
        return ('Unknown LED state', 400)
    return ('', 204)
```

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <label>Intervall in <strong>Minuten</strong>:</label>
    <input type="number" id="intervall" step="0.1" name='intervallMinuten'> </input>
    <h3>LED</h3>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type='button' id='led_on'>LED ON</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type='button' id='led_off'>LED OFF</button>
</div>
```

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

        <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
            // Setup button click handlers.
            $('#led_on').click(function() {
                console.log('LED on!');
              $.post('/led/1');
            });
            $('#led_off').click(function() {
                console.log('LED off!');
              $.post('/led/0');
            });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: You haven't submitted a form so there is no `request.form['intervallMinuten']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add 'intervallMinuten' in your post form, like this

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

        <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
            // Setup button click handlers.
            $('#led_on').click(function() {
                console.log('LED on!');
              $.post('/led/1',{intervallMinuten: 2});
            });
            $('#led_off').click(function() {
                console.log('LED off!');
              $.post('/led/0', {intervallMinuten: 2});
            });
            });
        </script>
```